# django-celery-beat not sending tasks to celery worker

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I was using celery only in django first.

This was my config,

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab


 os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'inventory.settings')
 app = Celery('inventory')

 app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
 #app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
 app.autodiscover_tasks()

 app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'send-report-every-single-minute': {
        'task': 'db.tasks.send_daily_report',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
     },
 }
```

And I ran celery worker and beat and the task worked.

```
celery -A inventory worker -l info
celery -A inventory beat -l info
```

But now, I am using the package, `django-celery-beat`.

I added the schedule in the django admin panel, and enabled the same task. But it does not send the task to the celery worker. The worker keeps on waiting. It is stuck on starting,

Neither does it show the task scheduled when I run the beat manually,

```
$ celery -A inventory beat -l debug

[2017-12-21 16:10:48,471: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2017-12-21 16:10:48,527: DEBUG/MainProcess] Current schedule:

[2017-12-21 16:10:48,527: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 minutes
[2017-12-21 16:10:48,528: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 minutes.
```

See, below `Current Schedule` line, it shows nothing but an empty line.

It happens only when I add task schedule through django admin panel.

**Neither does it shows the celery cleanup task in the django admin panel.**

Comment: got it, I was using the wrong scheduler when running the beat. I used django database scheduler and it started working